# A time variation in two cpp program implementing same thing

Tags: c++

I am writing a piece of code for a simple codeshef problem

> http://www.codechef.com/problems/INTEST/

this problem is pritty simple just reading the number from stdin and printing how many entered number is disible by number K.

I wrote my solution as

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  unsigned long  n,k,m;
    cin>>n>>k;
    int i;
    int count=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>m;
        if(m%k==0)
          count++;
    }
    cout<<count<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the online compiler said this "Time limit exceeded".

When I check the other's solution they are also doing the same thing except reading the number in the form of string and then converting this string to number using

> num=num*10 + (buffer-'0');

other's person solution.
http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/181250
this solution is working fine without any warning. Can anybody explain this problem of "time limit exceeded".

Comment: Can you please show some example input used for this program?

Comment: Probably `iostream` is just not fast enough.

Comment: @zch: Possibly, although 2.5MB/s doesn't sounds that high a hurdle to clear.

Comment: Input

The input begins with two positive integers n k (n, k<=107). The next n lines of input contain one positive integer ti, not greater than 109, each.
Output

Write a single integer to output, denoting how many integers ti are divisible by k.
Example

Input:
7 3
1
51
966369
7
9
999996
11

Output:
4

Comment: Have you measured the throughput of your code on your system (using a large input file). How does it compare to the required 2.5MB/s?

Comment: @NPE I donot have I any Idea to how to do this